# Excel 2019 - How To Detect The Selection Made On Excel Main Menu "File" Dropdown Using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

How do I detect the selection made in the File dropdown of the Excel 2019 main menu using VBA?  I am specifically trying to capture the Close selection in the File dropdown.  Is this possible?

The specific problem I'm having is that I want to display the Trust Center's MacroSecurity window (`Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("MacroSecurity")`) to the user using the ThisWorkbook module's Workbook_BeforeClose event and it errors when the user clicks the red "X" that closes Excel (I'm *assuming* because the Excel CommandBars environment has been closed).  Using Excel's main menu "File" option and selecting "Close" closes only the workbook, so the MacroSecurity window displays correctly before closing the workbook.  If I had a main menu File selection event that I could write code to I would be able to limit closing the workbook AND displaying the MacroSecurity window to only the selection of the "Close" option in the "File" main menu.

From my research it appears the the red "X" and the File>Close options are both tied to the ThisWorkbook module's Workbook_BeforeClose event.  If that's correct, is there any way to determine which method triggered the Workbook_BeforeClose event - the red "X" or the File>Close selection (or the keyboard, etc.)?

Comment: Can you tell us **why** do you need that? We maybe can help you to accomplish the need in a (simpler) different way...

Comment: @Stax, I'm already familiar with those options.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Bill,

I've been using the following code for years and it catches the Red X. File->Close and even Application.Quit typed in the VBE Immediate window.

```
Option Explicit

' Programmed by: RetiredGeek
' Date         : 22 Jul 2005    Version: 1.0
' Updated      : 14 Aug 2017    Version: 3.0
' Location     : ThisWorkbook

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)

   
       If (bMenuExit = True) Then
         Cancel = False
       Else
           MsgBox "Please use the Menu's to Exit the System" & vbCrLf & _
                  "Closing using the X will cause serious" & vbCrLf & _
                  "system problems!", vbOKOnly + vbCritical, _
                  "Error: Improper Attempt to Exit System"
           Cancel = True
           
       End If
   
End Sub                  'Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)


'                         +-------------------------+             +----------+
'-------------------------|     Exit_Program()      |-------------| 09/02/14 |
'                         +-------------------------+             +----------+
'Called by: ExitSave()  'These are routines triggered by Custom Ribbon setup (Icons)
'           ExitQuit()
'Calls    :
'Functions:
'Location : Any Standard Module

Public bMenuExit as Boolean  '*** Declared outside of any Subroutine ***

Sub Exit_Program(zSaveData As Boolean)

  Dim oSheet          As Object
  Dim bExcelVer10Plus As Boolean
   
   With Application
   
       .ScreenUpdating = False
       .DisplayAlerts = False
       
 '*** Your Exit Programming Here ***    
 
       bMenuExit = True
       ThisWorkbook.Saved = True
       .Quit
       
   End With  'Application
   
End Sub                        'Exit Program
```

Sample calling routine for Exit_Program():

```
'                         +-------------------------+             +----------+
'-------------------------|       ExitQuit()        |-------------| 07/13/20 |
'                         +-------------------------+             +----------+
'Called by: Menu Item
'Calls    : Exit_Program()
'Functions:

Sub ExitQuit(control As IRibbonControl)

   Exit_Program False
   
End Sub
```

HTH

Comment: Are these calls something you created on the Ribbon or are they part of the default Excel Ribbon: ExitSave()   and ExitQuit()?

Comment: Bill, I was using this code before the Ribbon existed. When I created my custom ribbons I just set the callback to ExitSave & ExitQuit respectively. Each of those routines simply pass the value for  zSaveData.  I've modified my answer to include the ExitQuit routine for  reference.

Comment: Am I correct in understanding that you created a custom menu item whose event was the ExitQuit() sub?  So, when the custom menu item was selected, the ExitQuit() sub code was run?  I've never customized Excel's menus or Ribbons.

Comment: That is correct.  I used Office Ribbon Editor.  Then I looked at the code it created and noticed I could shortcut the callback by adding the declaration to my already code.

Comment: Your approach would mean that I would have to use the Office Ribbon Editor to create custom menu items to do what you have done, correct?

Comment: Not necessarily, I was using this code pre ribbon by creating toolbar menus. In current versions of Excel they have to be accessed via the AddIns Ribbon selection.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229023/discussion-between-retiredgeek-and-bill-vallance).

Comment: Thanks, RetiredGeek, for the follow-up via chat. What I'm looking for is the ability to use only the default Excel Ribbon, not custom Ribbon options that require end user education. Being able to discriminate between the Excel red "X" and the File>Close methods of closing a workbook is what I'm looking for.

Comment: Bill, I don't know of any way to discriminate between the two actions as they both trigger the same event - WorkbookBeforeClose.